# WordPress wp_editor HTML display in frontend is not formatting properly

Tags: php, wordpress

When I paste the following content into `wp_editor`:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget
>   enim eu nulla imperdiet vulputate euismod ac purus. Fusce at faucibus
>   neque, et imperdiet velit. Suspendisse at est sagittis, porttitor
>   ipsum non, ullamcorper nulla. Sed vel nisi molestie nunc suscipit
>   tristique et in purus.
>
> Aenean volutpat, est in aliquet fermentum, turpis elit pharetra
>   libero, et posuere purus mi ac quam. Cras lobortis faucibus arcu, sed
>   pretium purus euismod id. Nam nec dictum neque. Maecenas sed ipsum
>   erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
>   posuere cubilia Curae; Proin tincidunt orci quis congue iaculis. Duis
>   at ipsum libero.
>
> Phasellus libero sapien, vehicula in augue et, placerat dignissim dui.
>   Mauris quis metus a ipsum tincidunt dapibus vel vel enim. Suspendisse
>   euismod, purus elementum facilisis malesuada, lorem purus dapibus
>   erat, a dictum diam lacus nec purus.

It will be displayed in the frontend like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget enim eu nulla imperdiet vulputate euismod ac purus. Fusce at faucibus neque, et imperdiet velit. Suspendisse at est sagittis, porttitor ipsum non, ullamcorper nulla. Sed vel nisi molestie nunc suscipit tristique et in purus. Aenean volutpat, est in aliquet fermentum, turpis elit pharetra libero, et posuere purus mi ac quam. Cras lobortis faucibus arcu, sed pretium purus euismod id. Nam nec dictum neque. Maecenas sed ipsum erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin tincidunt orci quis congue iaculis. Duis at ipsum libero. Phasellus libero sapien, vehicula in augue et, placerat dignissim dui. Mauris quis metus a ipsum tincidunt dapibus vel vel enim. Suspendisse euismod, purus elementum facilisis malesuada, lorem purus dapibus erat, a dictum diam lacus nec purus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use [`nl2br`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) on what comes from your DB here.

Because HTML doesn't compute `new line` (`\n` or `\r`) but does understand `<br/>`.